# Same Color for Bar Charts as a Scatter Plot

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to create a bar chart such that the color of bars corresponds to the colors of a previously plotted scatter plot. Here is an example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

array = np.random.rand(100,2)
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=10)
kmeans.fit(array)
y_kmeans = kmeans.predict(array)

y_kmeans_df = pd.DataFrame(y_kmeans)
y_kmeans_df.columns = ['Values']
y_kmeans_df.Values.value_counts(normalize=True)

fig, (ax0,ax1) = plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(10,15))
ax0.scatter(array[:,0], array[:,1], c=y_kmeans, s=50, cmap='viridis')

ax1.bar(y_kmeans_df.Values.value_counts(sort=False).index ,
       y_kmeans_df.Values.value_counts(normalize=True, sort=True).values)
ax1.set_xticks(y_kmeans_df.Values.value_counts(sort=False).index)
ax1.set_xticklabels(y_kmeans_df.Values.value_counts(sort=True).index)

plt.show()
```

[image]

So using matplotlib, I would like the bar colors to be the same color as their corresponding cluster in this case. I am not sure how to achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using `plt.get_cmap` and the `color` parameter in ax.bar plot:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

array = np.random.rand(100,2)
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=10)
kmeans.fit(array)
y_kmeans = kmeans.predict(array)

y_kmeans_df = pd.DataFrame(y_kmeans)
y_kmeans_df.columns = ['Values']
y_kmeans_df.Values.value_counts(normalize=True)

fig, (ax0,ax1) = plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(10,15))
ax0.scatter(array[:,0], array[:,1], c=y_kmeans, s=50, cmap='viridis')

vir = plt.get_cmap('viridis', 10)

ax1.bar(y_kmeans_df.Values.value_counts(sort=False).index ,
       y_kmeans_df.Values.value_counts(normalize=True, sort=True).values,
       color=vir(y_kmeans_df.Values.value_counts(sort=True).index))
ax1.set_xticks(y_kmeans_df.Values.value_counts(sort=False).index)
ax1.set_xticklabels(y_kmeans_df.Values.value_counts(sort=True).index)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I changed `color=vir(y_kmeans_df.Values.value_counts(sort=False).index` to `color=vir(y_kmeans_df.Values.value_counts(sort=True).index)` and it gave me what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: I modified the solution to match your desired results.  You're welcome.  Happy coding!